# RXJS: Reference to one of event producers changed in runtime

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm implementing following case:

We have multiple exactly same forms. One of the forms is a 'master' form, content of other forms is being compared to master form content. The purpose is to check if form is filled the same as 'master' form. Both 'master' and other forms are being changed over time.

My implementation is working perfectly fine:

Registering master form source:

```
    public setMasterFormValueSource(masterValue$: Observable<SomeFormValue>, initialValue: SomeFormValue): void {
        this._masterFormValue$ = masterValue$.pipe(
            startWith(initialValue)
        );
    }
```

Returning Observable for other forms:

```
public isSameAsForm$(formToCompare$: Observable<SomeFormValue>): Observable<boolean> {

        return combineLatest(this._masterFormValue$, formToCompare$).pipe(
            map(([formValue1, formValue2]) => areObjectsEqual(formValue1, formValue2)),
            distinctUntilChanged()
        );

    }
```

**PROBLEM:**

In some moment `setMasterFormValueSource` function is being called again setting new `this._masterFormValue$`. The problem is all other forms are listening on changes of old `this._masterFormValue$`. Is there a way to 'hot swap' master form value producer?

Comment: You're probably looking for `switchMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn `this._masterFormValue$` into an observable of observables and use `switchMap`:

```
private readonly _masterFormValue$ = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<SomeFormValue>>(of(undefined));

public setMasterFormValueSource(
    masterValue$: Observable<SomeFormValue>, initialValue: SomeFormValue
): void {
    this._masterFormValue$.next(masterValue$.pipe(
        startWith(initialValue)
    ));
}

public isSameAsForm$(formToCompare$: Observable<SomeFormValue>): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._masterFormValue$.pipe(
        switchMap(masterForm$ => combineLatest(masterForm$, formToCompare$).pipe(
            map(([formValue1, formValue2]) => areObjectsEqual(formValue1, formValue2)),
            distinctUntilChanged()
        ))
    );
}
```

Using `BehaviorSubject` makes sure we keep the reference to the current master form for new calls to `isSameAsForm$`.

However, using nested observables may be confusing. It may be easier to keep the reference to the form itself and obtain the observable inside `switchMap`:

```
private readonly _masterFormValue$ = new BehaviorSubject<MasterForm>(undefined);

public setMasterFormValueSource(form: MasterForm, initialValue: SomeFormValue): void {
    this._masterFormValue$.next(form);
}

public isSameAsForm$(formToCompare$: Observable<SomeFormValue>): Observable<boolean> {
    return combineLatest(
        this._masterFormValue$.pipe(switchMap(form => form ? form.values$ : [])),
        formToCompare$
    ).pipe(
        map(([formValue1, formValue2]) => areObjectsEqual(formValue1, formValue2)),
        distinctUntilChanged()
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Emitting new sources via BehaviorSubject works perfectly.